# VUE 3 - watch not returning correct values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In a Vue 3 app, I am referencing store getter and watching the change in its value to do some logic.

I need to compare the old and new values. However, I am getting the same values for each argument passed to the watch function.

Here is my setup:

```html
<script>
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import { watch } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup() {
    const store = useStore()
    let text = store.getters['SOME_ARRAY']
    
    watch(text, (text, prevText) => {
      console.log(text.length, prevText.length)
    })    
  }

   return { text }
}

</script>
```

In the `console.log` both lenghts are the same (ie, 3 3, 4 4, 5 5...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text` should use [`computed`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#computed-values) on the getter, so that its reference in the `watch` is kept up to date:

```js
// let text = store.getters['SOME_ARRAY']
let text = computed(() => store.getters['SOME_ARRAY']) ✅
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/watching-a-store-getter-in-vue-3-ycjiq?file=/src/App.vue:264-321)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
store.watch(() => store.getters['SOME_ARRAY'], (oldValue, newValue) => {
  console.log(oldValue)
  console.log(newValue)
})
```

Comment: what about this?

Comment: So, the store doesn't have a `watch` property as far as I know.

Comment: Well... learnt something new. But it still doesn't work :)